# How to print elongated pages

Tags: printing, gimp, preview

I have an ESP 3200 Kodak printer. It does a great job at printing however I am making skateboards and using heat transfer vinyl, and printing it in sections rather than a single page. I have recently ordered 100' of the transfer vinyl and am cutting it into 8.5" x 33" segments. I have changed the page layout to landscape, watched a few YouTube videos on how people do it with Excel to no avail simply because they never even did it themselves. They simply show the instructions and they didn't work, and showed no proof of completing the task. I am using GIMP image editor on a 2009 Mac Pro, and the Preview app. I am able to set the page settings in System Preferences and the page layout in print preview to 214mm x 838mm and 8.5" by 33" respectively, however I believe it's behaving like a graphics program in that it's showing scaling problems on pages after changing the printers default paper size in System Preferences and not printing the entire document, rather one page at a time. There is a possibility it will not print larger than 14 inches however the printer seems to handle the paper correctly and it makes me wonder if there's something wrong in my settings. It could be the file format too as Mac OS X seems to default to PDF, which is obviously arranged by pages.

Comment: Many printers aren't not designed to handle anything but the standard paper sizes. And if the printer is technically able, the drivers will limit it to the normal sizes.

Comment: I understand that, however the printer is controlled by terminal commands in the Unix environment mainly. What type of printer would you suggest?

Comment: It has to be added in the .ppd file. I don't know if you could mark this as a duplicate question but I believe it's a mix of arts and crafts and stackoverflow. You may want to leave an answer here as it was somewhat difficult for me to find one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028891/whats-the-easiest-way-to-add-custom-page-sizes-to-a-ppd/3112256#3112256

Comment: OP can you clarify? Are you trying to print the design on one single sheet that is 8.5" x 33" or on multiple 8.5"x11" or 14" sheets and then assembling them on the board? If it is the former, how are you feeding a 33" sheet into the 3200?

Comment: One 8.5" sheet 33" in length, cut from a roll.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to print outside of the standard document length, for instance printing onto a roll.

open terminal, or command shell, or optional windows bash prompt

`cd /etc/cups/ppd`

install vim first or use nano(program file editors)
(vim has a tutor just type vimtutor)

`sudo vim Eastman_Kodak_Company_KODAK_ESP_3200_Series_AiO.ppd`

scroll to the max height width and custom page params

`i` to insert
`ESC` to exit insert mode
`:wq!` to save and exit file

Note the width paramater will be named or in order of
width, height. The max width paramater should stay the same or it will throw the printers alignment off, but you can set the length to anything I believe. Then your printer will not create length boundaries in page setup and will allow you to print in continuous loop with no margin. Make sure your paper length is cut according to your page layout or it will simply spit out the rest of the roll.
This was my first try at it and I accidentally changed the width paramaters which were 712 I believe.

[image]