# How to print elongated pages

Tags: printing

I have an ESP 3200 Kodak printer. It does a great job at printing however I am making skateboards and using heat transfer vinyl, and printing it in sections rather than a single page. I have recently ordered 100' of the transfer vinyl and am cutting it into 8.5" x 33" segments. I have changed the page layout to landscape, watched a few YouTube videos on how people do it with Excel to no avail simply because they never even did it themselves. They simply show the instructions and they didn't work, and showed no proof of completing the task. I am using GIMP image editor on a 2009 Mac Pro, and the Preview app. I am able to set the page settings in System Preferences and the page layout in print preview to 214mm x 838mm and 8.5" by 33" respectively, however I believe it's behaving like a graphics program in that it's showing scaling problems on pages after changing the printers default paper size in System Preferences and not printing the entire document, rather one page at a time. There is a possibility it will not print larger than 14 inches however the printer seems to handle the paper correctly and it makes me wonder if there's something wrong in my settings.

Comment: I reposted it on Super user thank you

Comment: The same question: [How to print elongated pages](https://superuser.com/questions/1545741/how-to-print-elongated-pages). I voted to close this migrated one. It should have been deleted from Arts & Crafts Stack Exchange at the moment the copy was posted here on Super User.